# Problem creating and returning jagged array (error std::bad_array_new_length)

Tags: c++, pointers, jagged-arrays

For this homework problem, we need to create a new jagged array with the code provided by our professor, print the array, and calculate the max, min, and sum of the array's contents. We are only allowed to edit the `createAndReturnJaggedArray()` and `printAndThenFindMaxMinSum(int**,int*,int*,int*)` functions, as the rest of the code was provided for us so we could check that we get the correct output.

I'm able to get the program to run, however after printing an initial string it terminates the program giving me the error `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_array_new_length' what(): std::bad_array_new_length`. I believe the problem is in my creation of the jagged array and my allocation of memory for the columns part of the array, however I used the notes we were given as reference and have no idea where the problem is coming from. The entire program is provided below. Thanks for any help!

**EDIT/NOTE**: We haven't learned vectors yet so we're not allowed to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

class JaggedArray {

public:

int numRows;
int *numColumnsInEachRow;
JaggedArray() {
    numRows = 11;
    numColumnsInEachRow = new int[numRows];
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        if (i <= numRows / 2) {
            numColumnsInEachRow[i] = i + 1;
        } else {
            numColumnsInEachRow[i] = numRows - i;
        }
    }
    readComputeWrite();
}

int **createAndReturnJaggedArray() { // COMPLETE THIS FUNCTION
    int **A = new int*[numRows];
    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){ //allocate columns in each row
        A[i] = new int[numColumnsInEachRow[i]];
        for(int j=0;j<numColumnsInEachRow[i];j++){
            if(i <= numRows/2)
                A[i][j] = (i + j);
            else
                A[i][j] = -1 * (i+j);
        }
    }
    return A;
}

void printAndThenFindMinMaxSum(int **A, int *maxPtr, int *minPtr, int *sumPtr) { // COMPLETE THIS FUNCTION
    maxPtr = new int[INT_MIN];
    minPtr = new int[INT_MAX];
    sumPtr = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<numColumnsInEachRow[i];j++){
           //1. print array
            if (j == (numColumnsInEachRow[i]-1))
                cout << A[i][j] << endl;
            else
                cout << A[i][j] << " ";

           //2. compute max, min, and sum
           sumPtr += A[i][j];
           if (A[i][j] > *maxPtr)
                maxPtr = new int[A[i][j]];
           if (A[i][j] < *minPtr)
                minPtr = new int[A[i][j]];
        }
    }
}

void print(int max, int min, int sum) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Max is " << max << "\n";
    cout << "Min is " << min << "\n";
    cout << "Sum is " << sum << "\n";
}

void readComputeWrite() {
    int max, min, sum;
    int **A = createAndReturnJaggedArray();
    cout << "*** Jagged Array ***" << endl;
    printAndThenFindMinMaxSum(A, &max, &min, &sum);
    print(max, min, sum);
}
};

int main() {
    JaggedArray jaf;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Joseph Wood Yes,  we haven't learned vectors yet and therefore are not allowed to use them. :\

Comment: @JosephWood good call, will do

Comment: `maxPtr = new int[INT_MIN];` looks a bit of a problem to me. Not sure what you are doing here, but `INT_MIN` is a big-ass NEGATIVE number. Arrays and negative numbers do not mix. `minPtr = new int[INT_MAX];` is possible, but could require 18 trillion bytes of RAM. Good luck with that. 9 trillion, sorry. Smurf. I'm way out. 9 **quintillion** bytes. Anyway lots of RAM.

Comment: @user4581301 yeah, that makes sense. In the homework instructions, our teacher suggested initializing `maxPtr` to `INT_MIN`, `minPtr` to `INT_MAX`, and `sumPtr` to 0. Is there a better way of writing this so it doesn't overflow the program?

Comment: Read a bit more. When computing min and max , you generally only need one number each. For example, to get the max value in an array, you only need to store the highest number you've seen so far, and the lowest so far for min. For average you need two variables: the sum of all the numbers you've seen so far (get a BIG data type to store this) and the number of numbers you've summed up.

Comment: @BoolBordan07 -- Just to let you know, there is a huge flaw in your code to create the 2D array, and you need to mention this to your teacher.  If any of those calls to `new[]` throw an exception, you have one big memory leak.  Nowhere in your code do you attempt to "roll back" all of the previous allocations you made during the jagged array creation.  This is one gigantic reason why using `std::vector` is advantageous, and why teaching this way of creating 2D arrays in the way you're being taught ultimately ends up being a waste of time (unless you can fix the issue mentioned).

Comment: In addition, your `JaggedArray` class itself leaks memory, since it lacks a proper destructor.  Maybe later on you will learn in your class how to implement this function (and copy constructor / assignment operator).  Otherwise you really only learned how to write very buggy code.

Answer (score 1):

As @user4581301 hints at, your problem is in `printAndThenFindMinMaxSum`. Simply changing it to the below solves your problem:

```
void printAndThenFindMinMaxSum(int **A, int &maxPtr, int &minPtr, int &sumPtr) { // COMPLETE THIS FUNCTION
    maxPtr = INT_MIN;
    minPtr = INT_MAX;
    sumPtr = 0;

    .
    .
    .
            sumPtr += A[i][j];
            if (A[i][j] > maxPtr)
                maxPtr = A[i][j];
            if (A[i][j] < minPtr)
                minPtr = A[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

We also need to change `readComputeWrite` to:

```
void readComputeWrite() {
    int max, min, sum;
    int **A = createAndReturnJaggedArray();
    cout << "*** Jagged Array ***" << endl;
    printAndThenFindMinMaxSum(A, max, min, sum);
    print(max, min, sum);
}
```

I would also recommend changing the name `minPtr`, `maxPtr`, and `sumPtr` to something more appropriate, as they aren't pointer at this point and represent primitive values.

You will note, that I changed pointers to references as this is a more natural adaptation for this type of operation. Essentially, passing by reference allow the user to operate on the passed value in a straightforward manner without the tedious task of making sure you dereference things at the appropriate time. It also allows one to operate in a less error prone manner.

Again, as @user4581301 shrewdly points out, the intent of this assignment was probably to deal with pointers. As such, there are a few things that need to be changed if the OP cannot use references. Observe:

```
void printAndThenFindMinMaxSum(int **A, int *maxPtr, int *minPtr, int *sumPtr) { // COMPLETE THIS FUNCTION
    *maxPtr = INT_MIN;  // Make sure to deference before assigning
    *minPtr = INT_MAX;  // Make sure to deference before assigning
    *sumPtr = 0;  // Make sure to deference before assigning

    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numColumnsInEachRow[i];j++){
            //1. print array
            if (j == (numColumnsInEachRow[i]-1))
                cout << A[i][j] << endl;
            else
                cout << A[i][j] << " ";

            //2. compute max, min, and sum
            *sumPtr += A[i][j];   // Make sure to deference before assigning
            if (A[i][j] > *maxPtr)  // Make sure to deference before comparing
                *maxPtr = A[i][j];  // Make sure to deference before assigning
            if (A[i][j] < *minPtr)  // Make sure to deference before comparing
                *minPtr = A[i][j];  // Make sure to deference before assigning
        }
    }
}
```

And the `readComputeWrite` can stay unaltered from the OP's original attempt.

In the OP's code, they are mainly forgetting to deference before assigning/comparing.

Comment: Oh ho! You switched to references on me! Better idea, but I'm not sure the instructor's going to allow references.

Comment: @user4581301, quick question. Why wouldn't the instructor allow references? I'm genuinely curious and believe you have a good reason for saying this.

Comment: The `// COMPLETE THIS FUNCTION` comment in the question and the opening paragraphs of the question text. I suspect the instructor handed over a skeleton code for the students to fill out, and they have to fill it out exactly. I once suffered through such assignments, but from instructors teaching Modula from the same lesson plan as for Pascal. The fact that the other language offers better solutions never seems to dawn on them.

Comment: @JosephWood thank you! that makes a lot more sense, I was probably overthinking it. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: No problem, but @user4581301 was the real hero and really illuminated the underlying issues.